# Why can't install specified mariadb version with readline library?

Tags: debian, software-installation, readline, mariadb

My os info:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1 (2021-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Locale setting:

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I installed mariadb according to the webpage's introduction.

[install mariadb](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-mariadb-10-6-on-debian-11/)

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install curl software-properties-common dirmngr -y
sudo curl -LsSO https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc
sudo chmod -c 644 mariadb_release_signing_key.asc
sudo mv -vi mariadb_release_signing_key.asc /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] https://mirror.realcompute.io/mariadb/repo/10.6/debian bullseye main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

Now you can get desired version such as below:

```
mariadb --version
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.4-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline EditLine wrapper
```

In my os, what i get is the following info:

```
mariadb --version
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.12-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

**Issue #1:** In my /etc/apt/sources.list, it is:

```
deb [arch=ppc64el,arm64,amd64] https://mirror.realcompute.io/mariadb/repo/10.6/debian bullseye main
deb-src [arch=ppc64el,arm64,amd64] https://mirror.realcompute.io/mariadb/repo/10.6/debian bullseye main
```

I have already specified the version -- `10.6` in `sources.list`, why is the installed version `10.5`?

**Issue #2:** I have already installed `libreadline-dev` in the os:

```
sudo  dpkg -l | grep  readline
ii  libreadline-dev:amd64                  8.1-1                           amd64        GNU readline and history libraries, development files
ii  libreadline8:amd64                     8.1-1                           amd64        GNU readline and history libraries, run-time libraries
ii  readline-common                        8.1-1                           all          GNU readline and history libraries, common files
```

Why it is `for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper` in the os after my installation instead of `for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline EditLine wrapper`as described in the webpage?

```
cat  /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrors.163.com/debian/ bullseye main non-free contrib
deb http://mirrors.163.com/debian/ bullseye-updates main non-free contrib
deb http://mirrors.163.com/debian/ bullseye-backports main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/debian/ bullseye main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/debian/ bullseye-updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/debian/ bullseye-backports main non-free contrib
deb http://mirrors.163.com/debian-security/ bullseye/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/debian-security/ bullseye/updates main non-free contrib
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye stable
deb [arch=ppc64el,arm64,amd64] https://mirror.realcompute.io/mariadb/repo/10.6/debian bullseye main
deb-src [arch=ppc64el,arm64,amd64] https://mirror.realcompute.io/mariadb/repo/10.6/debian bullseye main
```

Update with sources.list:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt list --upgradable
Hit:1 http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease                                                                                                                     
Get:3 http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [39.4 kB]                                                                                                    
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                
Get:5 http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye-backports InRelease [43.7 kB]                                                                                                  
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease [43.7 kB]                                                                                                   
Hit:7 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                                                                                                 
Ign:8 http://mirrors.163.com/debian-security bullseye/updates InRelease                                                                                                     
Err:9 http://mirrors.163.com/debian-security bullseye/updates Release                                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 112.90.131.246 80]
Hit:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye InRelease                                                   
Hit:10 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease                                          
Get:12 http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye-backports/main Sources.diff/Index [63.3 kB]
Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main amd64 Packages.diff/Index [63.3 kB]
Get:14 http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye-backports/main amd64 Packages.diff/Index [63.3 kB]
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/boltgolt/howdy/ubuntu impish InRelease [18.0 kB]       
Get:16 http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye-backports/main Sources T-2021-11-13-1401.28-F-2021-11-13-0801.26.pdiff [623 B]
Get:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main Translation-en.diff/Index [25.2 kB]
Get:16 http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye-backports/main Sources T-2021-11-13-1401.28-F-2021-11-13-0801.26.pdiff [623 B]
Get:18 http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye-backports/main amd64 Packages T-2021-11-13-1401.28-F-2021-11-13-1401.28.pdiff [191 B]
Get:18 http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye-backports/main amd64 Packages T-2021-11-13-1401.28-F-2021-11-13-1401.28.pdiff [191 B]
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/boltgolt/howdy/ubuntu impish InRelease            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8CEBC97F3E9E1D58
Get:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main amd64 Packages T-2021-11-13-2001.35-F-2021-11-13-1401.28.pdiff [14.5 kB]
Get:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main amd64 Packages T-2021-11-13-2001.35-F-2021-11-13-1401.28.pdiff [14.5 kB]
Get:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main Translation-en T-2021-11-13-2001.35-F-2021-11-13-2001.35.pdiff [9,997 B]
Get:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main Translation-en T-2021-11-13-2001.35-F-2021-11-13-2001.35.pdiff [9,997 B]
Err:21 https://mirror.realcompute.io/mariadb/repo/10.6/debian bullseye InRelease                                                                                            
  Connection failed [IP: 114.141.111.226 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                               
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.163.com/debian-security bullseye/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/boltgolt/howdy/ubuntu impish InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8CEBC97F3E9E1D58
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/boltgolt/howdy/ubuntu impish InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Check the /var/cache/apt/archives first. dpkg --contents <installedmysqlpackagename>

Comment: Can you add the entire contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` please?

Comment: Also, can you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt list --upgradable` and give us the output?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using mirrors.163.com as your Debian mirror?

Comment: It is more faster than other Debian sources in my area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Upgrading MariaDB

OK, it looks like you have a few issues with entries in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` that need to be addressed (see the section below for more), although as far as I can tell these aren't related to your issue with MariaDB.  The entries for the MariaDB 10.6 repo seem to be working fine.

From the information you've given me, my best guess is that MariaDB's version is being held back at 10.5.12 due to it being already installed *before* the more up-to-date MariaDB repository was added to your `sources.list`. My guess is that running `sudo apt upgrade` looks something like this:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  mariadb-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

`apt` does not upgrade MariaDB to 10.6 automatically because doing so would require some 10.5-specific dependency packages to be removed. Solving that issue should be as simple as specifying the `mariadb-server` and `mariadb-client` packages to be upgraded explicitly. Just run `sudo apt upgrade mariadb-server mariadb-client` and the prompt should look something like this:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade mariadb-server mariadb-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libconfig-inifiles-perl
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mariadb-client-10.5 mariadb-client-core-10.5 mariadb-server-10.5 mariadb-server-core-10.5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdaxctl1 libndctl6 libpmem1 liburing1 mariadb-client mariadb-client-10.6 mariadb-client-core-10.6 mariadb-server-10.6 mariadb-server-core-10.6
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mariadb-server
1 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 5,323 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

If so, just enter `y` to continue and then verify that MariaDB version 10.6 is installed with `mariadb --version`:

```
$ mariadb --version
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.5-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline EditLine wrapper
```

As a side note in regards to Issue #2 in your question, version 10.5's `mariadb --version` output *should* read `using  EditLine wrapper` and not `using readline Editline wrapper`. That particular quirk is completely normal and has nothing to do with the presence of `libreadline-dev`.

---

### Side Note: Debian Security Mirrors

As I said earlier, you have some issues with your `sources.list` that need to be addressed. This is outside the scope of your MariaDB issue, but I'm going to go on a short tangent here to get the most important of those issues fixed since this is security-related.

These two `debian-security` sources use the old format from Debian 10 (Buster) and earlier, which was changed during the upgrade to Debian 11 (Bullseye). You can see they are creating errors in the output of `sudo apt update`.

```
deb http://mirrors.163.com/debian-security/ bullseye/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/debian-security/ bullseye/updates main non-free contrib
```

Those lines should be deleted and replaced with the new format. [Debian's security team do not encourage using mirrors for security repos](https://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror#:%7E:text=We%20recommend%20debian-security%20not%20be%20mirrored.), so here are the official mirrors.

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
```

There are also some other errors coming from source files inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` but fixing those is outside of the scope of this question. Look at the errors in the output of `sudo apt update` if you want to fix those on your own.